# Compile error for zxing library

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5

```
ZXPDF417Codeword *codeword = [self.detectionResultColumnsInternal[barcodeColumn] codewords][codewordsRow];
```

/My Projects/in Loyal SVN/new source Inloyal/ProjectCode_Inloyal_21-May/ZBarSDK/ZXingObjC/pdf417/decoder/ZXPDF417DetectionResult.m:144:38: Expected method to read array element not found on object of type 'NSString *'

Answer (score 0):

Replace it with:

```
ZXPDF417Codeword *codeword = ((NSArray *)[self.detectionResultColumnsInternal[barcodeColumn] codewords])[codewordsRow];
```

It should work I think.